# How JButton of one class append text to JTextArea of another class

Tags: java, swing, oop

I'm trying to add my `addText()` method (or `append()` method) of `JTextArea` of one class to `JButton` located in another class.

I don't wanna to create new object in `JButton` or make method static, I have read some answers on this forum but I can't apply it to my code, so please help me to fix this code:

```
class Frame extends JFrame {
    public Frame() {
        TextArea textarea = new TextArea();
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(dim());
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(textarea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    private Dimension dim() {
        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension d = kit.getScreenSize();
        int width = (int)(d.getWidth() / 2);
        int height = (int)(d.getHeight() / 2);
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }
}
class TextArea extends JTextArea {
    public TextArea() {}
    public void addText(String s) {
        append(s);
    }
}
class Panel extends JPanel {
    public Panel() {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setText("Start");
        button.addActionListener(new Button());
        add(button);
    }
    class Button extends JButton implements ActionListener {
        public Button() {}@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd start by not extending `JFrame`, `JTextArea`, `JPanel` **or** `JButton` .. and even if you were extending them, they should *not* have names with equivalents in the AWT package!  That is just plain confusing.  What functionality of any of those three classes do you feel you need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an anonymous class and delete the `Button` class. I do not see the need of having a class extending from `JButton` if you're already using `JButton` in your main code.

---

### Solution

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        // setText() or append();
    }
});
```

Comment: Im still learning, I made this code only for question purpose so it it possible to make it work without changing this code ?

Comment: @user5671675 It is possible of course, but it will add a lot more complexity to the code. I do not think this is adviced.

Comment: OK, it's very good answer! Back to basics its allways best idea, also I should make code clear and simple :)